# Compare two different RDDs using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, compare, rdd

I have two RDDs- one from hdfs file system and the other created from a string as shown below-

```
val txt=sc.textFile("/tmp/textFile.txt")

val str="This\nfile is\nallowed"
val strRDD=sc.parallelize(List(str))
```

[image]

[image]

Now, I want two compare the data in these two RDDs:
[image]

OR

[image]

The result should be an empty RDD but that is not the case. Can someone please explain **how I should compare the data of these two RDDs**?

Comment: those two rdds are not same. so how can the result be empty?

Comment: If the files are this small, using pure scala for the comparison would be easier than involving Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Values of the two rdds that you've created looks to be same but are not same*. It is evident if you do the count of elements in both rdds as

```
txt.collect().count(!_.isEmpty)
//res0: Int = 3

strRDD.collect().count(!_.isEmpty)
//res1: Int = 1
```

> > The result should be an empty RDD but that is not the case.

Thats the reason the results of `txt.subtract(strRDD)` and `strRDD.subtract(txt)` are not same

`val txt=sc.textFile("/tmp/textFile.txt")` gives each line as separate element in `txt` *RDD*

`val str="This\nfile is\nallowed"
val strRDD=sc.parallelize(List(str))` gives one `\n` separated element in `strRDD` *RDD*

I hope the explanation is clear

Comment: yes, the explanation is clear, thanks. Is there any way I can compare a string RDD and RDD from an hdfs file?

Comment: You will have to create identical data. thats all